# Force GAE to update all files on deployment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to force GAE to upload and update all files, even if it thinks it doesn't require any updations?
Clarification - If I make quick back-to-back updates, I find that certain files, that were definitely modified, refuse to be updated online. Apart from assigning version numbers to force the update, which is very painful, is there another way?

EDIT - I'm referring to javascript files

Comment: How do you know they refuse to be updated? Is it possible that a file is cached on your end and so appears to not have updated? I enjoyed "updations" also: a great improvement on the boring "updates".

Comment: lol, I'm trying not to kill myself here. I've cleared all forms of cache, and I've looked at my source code, it's untouched

Comment: what certain files are not being updated?  If you mean css, js and you are running a custom domain then the google edge cache will be in affect.  If this is the case you will need to adopt cache busting techniques.

Comment: I should probably add that t the question, yes I'm talking about js files

Comment: This is almost certainly a caching issue. Try accessing the script with a query string parameter (anything you've never used before) appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files **do** get updated, you don't see the update because of caching that happens in some where a long the chain. In order to get the latest files load the file with a slug (e.g. http://myapp.com/scripts/script.js?**slug**) and update the slug each time you deploy your application.

Comment: doesn't that become almost like versioning?

Comment: Is there an easy way yo maintain version numbers? I don't want to have to keep changing them while referencing them

Comment: Not out of the box, but you could put a static slug in the code and once you deploy copy the source and replace the static slug with some sort of a global version, md5 of the file or the file version from the source control.